# How can I use a certain class as String?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, class, types

Code1

```
public class Human
{
    private string h_name = "";
    private string h_gender = "Male";
    private int h_age = 0;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return h_name; }
        set { h_name = value; }
    }
    public string Gender
    {
        get { return h_name; }
        set { h_name = value; }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return h_age; }
        set { h_age = value; }
    }

}
```

Code2

```
public class Here
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Human hm = new Human();
        hm.Name = "Bill";
        hm.Gender = "Male";
        hm.Age = 20;
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to use the variable "hm" as String where hm will return the Name property... something like:

```
string person = hm;
Console.WriteLine(person + " has greeted you!");
```

What will I do? Should I make an Extension or something?

---

I overridden the ToString() method, and yes, it works on Console.WriteLine()

but now, I want to store it as string in a string variable

```
string person = hm;
Console.WriteLine(person);
```

and I get this

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Human' to 'string'
```

I also want to use it in my VB.NET program, but it gives me this error when I concatenate it:

```
Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Human'
```

---

Comment: use : string person = hm.name;

Comment: If you put string person = hm; you assign to string person an object hm that will trow an error.

Comment: As an aside, you should learn about automatically implemented properties - your current class could be implemented in three lines.

Comment: ... and you *probably* should use an enum for the gender

Comment: oh, I forgot to change the Gender... tee-hee~

Answer (score 5):

You can declare an `implicit` conversion from your type to `string` using [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tk49fh2.aspx). But it's a bad idea. I suggest you to *override* `ToString` method in your class instead, then you can just output it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(hm + " has greeted you!");
```

There is also a good documentation on how to override `ToString` method

- [How To: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I really thought of overriding the ToString() method, though, it comes in my mind that I still have to use hm.ToString() which is still the same as hm.Name... but I didn't know it could return the string directly... Thank you very much it really helped me so much!

Comment: oh wait, rather, can I use this when comparing strings in VB.NET after compilation?

Comment: Example: 
            If human = humanN Then
                Return True
            End If

Comment: @Pat-kunTeruel I don't know VB.NET, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

An implicit convention by adding the following to the `Human` class would work

```
public static implicit operator string(Human h)
    {
        return h.Name;
    }
```

Although i think the best way is to override the `ToString` Method like so

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `ToString` method:

```
public class Human
{
    private string h_name = "";
    private string h_gender = "Male";
    private int h_age = 0;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return h_name; }
        set { h_name = value; }
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return h_name; }
        set { h_name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return h_age; }
        set { h_age = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `ToString()` method.

```
public class Human
    {
    public override ToString() { return Name }

    private string h_name = "";
    private string h_gender = "Male";
    private int h_age = 0;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return h_name; }
        set { h_name = value; }
    }
    public string Gender
    {
        get { return h_name; }
        set { h_name = value; }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return h_age; }
        set { h_age = value; }
    }
}
```

Your code would then look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(hm + " has greeted you!");
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>`vb.net` answer:</sup>

As state by others, you need to define a conversion  [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh17yw4c.aspx). If you want to support string concatenation then you also need to define the `&` operator.

```vb
Public Class Human

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As Human) As String
        Return value.Name
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator &(left As Human, right As String) As String
        Return (left.Name & right)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator &(left As String, right As Human) As String
        Return (left & right.Name)
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Name
    End Function

End Class
```